# What is the Y-intercept?

Tags: graphing-functions

In class, my math teacher was teaching us how to draw **functions** on a *coordinate plane*, and he mentioned something about the **Y-Intercept** being an important step in creating/solving a **function**. But, what exactly is a **Y-Intercept**?

Comment: It's where the function intersects the $y$-axis.  I.e. where $x = 0$.

Comment: The function intersects the $y$-axis as a subset of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Say if $f : \mathbb{R} \to $ itself.  The graph of $f$ is $\{(x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and the $y$-axis is defined as the subset $\{(0, y) : y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.  Intersect the two sets.  Since $f$ is a function, by definition there is one and only one point in the intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $y$-intercept of a function $f(x)$ is the point where the function intersects the $y$-axis (if in fact it does intersect the $y$-axis) and it is found by evaluating $f(0)$, i.e., finding the value of $f(x)$ when $x = 0$.

For example,

- the line $f(x) = y = 3x + 2$ intersects the $x$-axis at when $x = 0$: 
  when $\;y = 3\cdot 0 + 2 = 2$. This is the function's y-intercept.
- The parabola $f(x) = y = 2x^2 + 8$ intersects the $y$-axis when $x = 0:\;$ 
  when $\;y = 2(0)^2 + 8 = 8$. This is the function's y-intercept.

Comment: Can you answer this in English? LOL sorry.

Comment: So you are saying that the Y axis is the point where the function intersects with the Y axis?

Comment: Yes, the y-intercept is the point where the function intersects the y-axis. To find it, just plug in $x = 0$ into the function, since $x = 0$ exactly at the y-axis.

Comment: @amWhy: Another TU from me! +1